# SQL Server 2005 Row update problem

Tags: sql-server-2005

After I pulled these datas what I wanted from a SQL Server Database,I can't update on row.I'm receiving the following the error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you have used the "Edit top x Rows" feature of Management Studio and wanted to update one row. In case that specific row was already deleted by another user/session then you'll receive the upper error.

I think it's better not use the Management Studio's results grid to update data, but use SQL commands. This way you'll work on last fresh data.

Comment: @ Marian- first of all,thanks for your interesting.As you said,I'm using T-SQL to update row.But,this process takes my long time.what should I do?

Comment: @Cell-o - that's a different problem. Most likely it's a missing index issue, but you'd better ask a different question about the statement and its duration.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using SQL commands is that you can also use different isolation levels to preserve the data you are viewing.